# Segue firing after destination View Controller loading

Tags: ios, ios8, segue

In my app I have a segue that fires in an ViewDidLoad of an initial View Controller. If a database setting is true the segue pushes to another View Controller. If the database is false/nil then no segue takes place.

**Initial VC**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

 if([database setting:SegueSetting])
 {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HasCreds" sender:self];
 }
```

The issue I have is that on iOS 8+, the segue pushes after the destination VC loads. This causes the initial VC to appear for a short time (up to a second) before the segue is fired. This is confirmed when a break point is placed in the Destination VC, the initial VC appears on device until viewDidLoad of the destination VC compiles. On versions previous to 8, the segue is pushed before the the destination VC loads. With a break point set in destination VC, the splash screen appears until viewDidLoad compiles. This is the intended action of my app. Any ideas why this is happening and an appropriate fix?

Comment: Can you move this code into the Application delegate? You will have to get your starboard and assuming you are inside a UINavigationController, programmatically update the initialViewControlller.

Comment: Yes, the View COntrollers are imbedded in a Navigation Controller. Putting a segue within the AppDelegate has the same issue.

Comment: You won't be able to perform the segue, but in applicationDidFinishLoading: can you get a reference to both your navigation controller and the 'HasCreds' ViewController from the storyboard? Then with these you should be able to set navController.initialViewController. This will mean you won't be able to pop back to the original view controller.